# use WHERE clause for offset in MySQL LIMIT

Tags: mysql

I want to perform a query, ordered across the entire result set, but with an offset for a specific row (based on a column value).

Basically:

```
SELECT * FROM users
ORDER BY reputation
LIMIT 3 OFFSET (WHERE users.id = 6)-1
```

Is there any way to perform a query like that?

For a table like:

```
USERS
id   reputation
1   33
2   34
3   40
4   53
5   45
6   44
```

Should return

```
id   reputation
3    40
6    44
5    45
```

So, I'm getting user with id=6, and the two users with the closest amount of reputation (one that is higher and one that is lower).

Comment: What is that offset supposed to do exactly? Does it increase the limit value by x? Does it skip all entries until ID=33 and then selected the next 3?

Comment: Can you post a row sample of the table, and the expected query output? It's difficult to understand how your requirement differs from simply saying `WHERE users.id >= 33` in the normal `WHERE` clause, after adding another column to the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I am not sure it will work or not..but you can give it a try. `select * from users ORDER BY reputation having reputation >= (select reputation from users where user.id = 33) limit 3`

Comment: @PardeepDhingra: Your solution would need `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` since it comes after the `ORDER BY`

Comment: I updated with example input and output. Sorry. Shoulda done that at first

Comment: @PardeepDhingra, yeah. Something like that would work. I would need to use that query, but also use a query with `having reputation <= ...`, and use a UNION, so I could get the <reputation, the id=6, and the >repuation. Was just hoping for something simpler, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return the reputation of the user with id = 6:

```
select reputation from USERS where id=6
```

And this will return the two users with reputation >= the one with id=6:

```
(select *
from USERS
where reputation >= (select reputation from USERS where id=6)
order by reputation
limit 2)
```

then you can return the two users with reputation <= the one with id=6:

```
(select *
from USERS
where reputation <= (select reputation from USERS where id=6)
order by reputation DESC
limit 2)
```

of course, both of those queries will return the user with id=6 twice (unless there are duplicated reputations), and one record with the following user, and the previous user. You can combine both with UNION (union will remove the duplicated row for the id=6):

```
(select *
from USERS
where reputation >= (select reputation from USERS where id=6)
order by reputation
limit 2)
union
(select *
from USERS
where reputation <= (select reputation from USERS where id=6)
order by reputation DESC
limit 2)
```

the only problem here is that reputation can be duplicated. Which records do you want to return on this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are considering row with users.id=33 as offset row, you can do what you want as give below-

Select * from (SELECT * FROM users
Order by users.id
LIMIT 3 OFFSET 32) tab
ORDER BY reputation